# DataApiBuilderException while trying to run swa start

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli, azure-static-web-app, data-api-builder

I'm trying to follow the instructions present in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/database-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=powershell) but I'm getting an error when trying to run `swa start`

```
swa start src --api-location api --data-api-location swa-db-connections
```

Everything was working fine before I tried to implement Cosmos DB, so, if I run the command without the `--data-api-location swa-db-connections` part, everything works fine.

I'm getting the following output:

```
Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.1.4)

***********************************************************************
* WARNING: This emulator may not match the cloud environment exactly. *
* Always deploy and test your app in Azure.                           *
***********************************************************************

[dataApi] Information: Microsoft.DataApiBuilder 0.9.6-rc+529471ba3b50e617439c57548891fdff7ec1c3fa
[dataApi] Information: User provided config file: staticwebapp.database.config.json
[dataApi] Loading config file from staticwebapp.database.config.json.
[dataApi] Information: Loaded config file: staticwebapp.database.config.json
[dataApi] Information: Setting default minimum LogLevel: Error for Production mode.
[dataApi] Starting the runtime engine...
[dataApi] Redirecting to https is disabled.
[dataApi] Loading config file from staticwebapp.database.config.json.
[swa]
[swa] Using workflow file:
[swa]   C:\Users\alexa\source\repos\az-lead\.github\workflows\azure-static-web-apps-icy-pebble-0c3175610.yml
[dataApi] info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[63]
[dataApi]       User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
[dataApi] fail: Azure.DataApiBuilder.Service.Startup[0]
[dataApi]       OpenAPI Documentor initialization failed.
[dataApi]       Azure.DataApiBuilder.Service.Exceptions.DataApiBuilderException: OpenAPI description document can't be created when the REST endpoint is disabled globally.
[dataApi]          at Azure.DataApiBuilder.Core.Services.OpenApiDocumentor.CreateDocument() in /_/src/Core/Services/OpenAPI/OpenApiDocumentor.cs:line 108
[dataApi]          at Azure.DataApiBuilder.Service.Startup.PerformOnConfigChangeAsync(IApplicationBuilder app) in /_/src/Service/Startup.cs:line 687
[dataApi] Unable to launch the runtime due to an error.
[dataApi] Error: Failed to start the engine.
[dataApi] cd "C:\Users\alexa\source\repos\az-lead\swa-db-connections" && "C:\Users\alexa\.swa\dataApiBuilder\0.9.6-rc\Microsoft.DataApiBuilder.exe" start -c staticwebapp.database.config.json --no-https-redirect exited with code 0
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[swa] node "C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\dist\msha\server.js" exited with code 1
✖ SWA emulator stoped because SWA emulator exited with code 1.
```

---

staticwebapp.database.config.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/latest/download/dab.draft.schema.json",
  "data-source": {
    "database-type": "cosmosdb_nosql",
    "options": {
      "database": "MyTestPersonDatabase",
      "schema": "staticwebapp.database.schema.gql"
    },
    "connection-string": "@env('DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING')"
  },
  "runtime": {
    "graphql": {
      "allow-introspection": true,
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "/graphql"
    },
    "host": {
      "mode": "production",
      "cors": {
        "origins": ["http://localhost:4280"],
        "allow-credentials": false
      },
      "authentication": {
        "provider": "StaticWebApps"
      }
    }
  },
  "entities": {
    "Person": {
      "source": "MyTestPersonContainer",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "actions": ["*"],
          "role": "anonymous"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

staticwebapp.database.schema.gql

```
type Person @model {
  id: ID
  Name: String
}
```

---

staticwebapp.config.json

```
{
    "responseOverrides": {
      "404": {
        "rewrite": "/404.html"
      },
      "401": {
        "redirect": "/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_uri=.referrer",
        "statusCode": 302
      }
    },
    "routes": [
      {
        "route": "/admin*",
        "allowedRoles": ["administrator"]
      },
      {
        "route": "/company*",
        "allowedRoles": ["operator", "manager"]
      },
      {
        "route": "/api/postLogin",
        "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
      },
      {
        "route": "/.auth/login/twitter",
        "statusCode": 404
      },
      {
        "route": "/.auth/login/github",
        "statusCode": 404
      },
      {
        "route": "/.auth/login/google",
        "statusCode": 404
      },
      {
        "route": "/.auth/login/facebook",
        "statusCode": 404
      }
    ]
  }
```

I've already tryed:

- deleting everything from my database and creating again
- deleting every file associated with the tutorial and creating again

Comment: are you getting this error locally? also can you paste the whole error?

Comment: I'm getting this error on my Windows 11 computer, got the same error when trying to run the command trough Ubuntu WSL. The whole output is present in my post

Comment: To investigate further, could you please modify the host.mode property in the config from "production" to "development" and run again. This will give us more logs to find out what might be happening.

Comment: do you have an update/

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/database-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=powershell) for creating this project and I got the output when I run this command

```bash
swa start ./src --data-api-location swa-db-connections
```

[image]

Output :
[image]

Azure Cosmosdb :
[image]

Make sure Cosmosdb Connectionstring is present in
.env file :

```html
DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING='AccountEndpoint=https://AzureCosmosDBaccount.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=accountkey'
```

staticwebapp.database.config.json :

```json
{
"$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/latest/download/dab.draft.schema.json",
"data-source": {
"database-type": "cosmosdb_nosql",
"options": {
"database": "DatabaseName",
"schema": "staticwebapp.database.schema.gql"
},
"connection-string": "@env('DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING')"
},
"runtime": {
"graphql": {
"allow-introspection": true,
"enabled": true,
"path": "/graphql"
},
"host": {
"mode": "production",
"cors": {
"origins": ["http://localhost:4280"],
"allow-credentials": false
},
"authentication": {
"provider": "StaticWebApps"
}
}
},
"entities": {
"Person": {
"source": "ContainerName",
"permissions": [
{
"actions": ["*"],
"role": "anonymous"
}
]
}
}
}
```

staticwebapp.database.schema.gql :

```js
type Person @model {
  id: ID
  Name: String
}
```

Comment: Your answers clarified for me that I copied the primary key instead of the connection string. However, I still got the following error: "[dataApi] Unable to launch the runtime due to: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use."

Comment: All right, I tried again on Linux machine, and it is working...